# automatic token renewal issue with keycloak versions and Spring Boot App with JS frontend

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak

With Spring Security adapter for keycloak ver 3.4.0 REST calls made from the JS elements of the app to the same app's java backend, the calls are able to renew the access token automatically, when we try to update the adapter to 3.4.3.FINAL the calls die when the token expires and there is no automatic token renewal.  As I understand, the correct behavior is shown in the 3.4.3 version where you need to add refresh logic to the JS code. is this correct?

Comment: You shouldn't need to add anything in javascript as it is the Spring Security adapter. If you find some mismatch between 3.4.0 and 3.4.3 adapters you might notify to the KC team, as there shouldn't be any in minor releases.

Comment: thing is, once the access token expires, the rest endpoints just throw a forbidden error. I guess my question then is, how does the js context becomes aware of the token renewal need?

Comment: In Ss adapter the only thing managed by the client is the session cookie. The access token lifecycle is managed by server side.

Comment: ok, gotcha, then why would the JS rest calls fail if this is the case?

Comment: solved. apparently this is a regression on 3.4.1 to 3.4.3. the new 4.0 beta reverts back to the previous behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MBatlle found out there was a regression from 3.4.1 to 3.4.3. We couldn't upgrade our platform since we are using RedhatSSO so we just patched the problematic class: `KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter`.

We generated a fixed jar using the `KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter` class from 4.0.0.Beta3 into the 3.4.3.Final version and it solves the problem

Comment: oh wow thats great man! I will remember to keep an eye on this solution should we decide to move to the paid RH SSO.